# Extract two different types of values from a file and print it to an output file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file where the data looks like:

```
sp_0005_SySynthetic ConstructTumor protein p53 N-terminal transcription-activation domain
A=9 C=2 D=3 E=4 F=2 G=15 I=3 K=3 L=9 M=3 N=5 P=2 Q=11 R=8 S=12 T=6 V=8 W=1 Y=5
Amino acid alphabet = 19
Sequence length = 115

sp_0017_CaCamelidSorghum bicolor multidrug and toxic compound extrusion sbmate
A=10 C=2 D=4 E=4 F=2 G=15 H=1 I=2 K=4 L=7 M=2 N=5 P=3 Q=6 R=4 S=18 T=7 V=10 W=5 Y=10
Amino acid alphabet = 20
Sequence length = 126

sp_0021_LgLlamabotulinum neurotoxin BoNT serotype F
A=14 C=2 D=4 E=5 F=4 G=15 I=2 K=3 L=6 M=2 N=6 P=4 Q=7 R=8 S=13 T=10 V=8 W=3 Y=10
Amino acid alphabet = 19
Sequence length = 131
```

I want to extract the vales of 'Amino acid alphabet' and 'Sequence length into an output file', and it should look like:

```
19 115
20 126
19 131
```

As I am new to bash, all I could try so far is:

```
grep -i "Amino acid alphabet = $i" test.txt >>out.txt
```

But, I don't want the word "Amino acid alphabet" in the output. I only want the values of "Amino acid alphabet" and "Sequence length" as two columns.

Can I get any help how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @markp-fuso As I am new to bash, all I could try so far is:  `grep -i "Amino acid alphabet = $i" test.txt >>out.txt`  But, I don't want the word "Amino acid alphabet" in the output. I only want the values of "Amino acid alphabet" and "Sequence length" as two columns.

Comment: @Davi54, please wrap your samples in CODE TAGS(to make it clear looking wise). Also add your efforts which you shown in your comment in your question please.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 does it look better now? I tried putting my sample data in code tags and added my tried command in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Davi54 to format code, remember to use the `{}` button, or just indent the lines with 4 spaces. Do not use tags like `<br>` or `<pre>` etc around code. Cheers.

Comment: Oh, okay. My apologies, it's just my lack of experience with this. Will keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v RS= '{print $(NF-4), $NF}' file
19 115
20 126
19 131
```

Comment: `-v RS=` sets empty lines as the record separator? That's beautiful, @Ed, lol. A space on those lines will throw a monkey wrench, but I love it.

Comment: @PaulHodges yes, that's also known as "paragraph mode" and is the common approach for dealing with the fairly common problem of blocks of text separated by blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both fields exist for all your records:

```
awk '/^Amino acid alphabet/{printf $NF FS} /^Sequence length/{print $NF}' file
19 115
20 126
19 131
```

Also you may want to have some introduction about awk into the [awk wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info)

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, it shows the output on the terminal. Is there a way to print it into a file?

Comment: to print the output of any shell command into a file: `command > output_file.txt`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was using >> to print to file and it was giving me errors. I will read about the awk command too.

Answer (score 2):

This code: `grep -i "Amino acid alphabet = $i" test.txt >>out.txt` includes the shell expansion of `$i`.  If you have not given a value to `i` then the search pattern resolves to `Amino acid alphabet =` , and thus will find each line that contains that. The `$i` would change the search pattern if `$i` had a value.

There are many ways to get what you want with BASH.  one is to use grep with PCRE (Perl-style) regex enabled:

```
grep -Po "(?<=Amino acid alphapbet = )\d+" test.txt >> out.text
#yields:
19
20
19
```

`(?<=string)` tells grep that for the rest to match, it must have been preceded by `string`, but  `string` is not a part of the Match.  `-Po` are the options to enable PCRE (Perl Style) and to only print the match, rather than the whole line in which there was a match.

Note that the output redirect is `>>` if you want to append to a file if it already contains lines, `>` will overwrite an existing file if it exists, (without asking for confirmation!)

Comment: I see that you wanted it in columns for each type, which the above does not do, but can be done with a perl one-liner, but if you have a working solution like the one by thanasisp, I'll bow out.

Comment: @thanasisp Thanks!  I think it might be tricky to do in a single grep seeing as the requested strings are on different lines but output should be on one.  I would be inclined to wrap it in a perl -e ... but this seems far from what the OP wanted.

Comment: Yes right. Just trying to create an answer from this grep. Also `paste -d' ' <(grep pattern1) <(grep pattern2)` with exactly your grep command could work (for bash shell only)

Answer (score 2):

`sed` can do this too.

```
sed -En '/^Amino acid alphabet =/h; /^Sequence length =/{ H; x; s/[^0-9]+/ /g; s/^ //; p; }' infile > outfile
```

`/^Amino acid alphabet =/h` stores the first line in the save buffer.
`/^Sequence length =/{` triggers all the steps inside the curlies.
`H` adds the current line to the save buffer.
`x` swaps the save buffer back to the workspace.
`s/[^0-9]+/ /g;` changes every sequence on NON-digits to a single space.
This includes the newline.
`s/^ //;` removes the leading space.
`p` prints the output line for this data set.